# Calling a method, using a property

Tags: php, class, methods, properties

For a project I'm working on, I'm trying to call a method using a property

```
$this->action = "home";
$action = $this->action;
$this->$action();
```

Is there a shorter way to do this? I tried the following, but it won't work:

```
$this->action = "home";
$this->$this->action();
```

So I want to set the $action property, and then call the method that has the same name as $action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
$this->action = "home";
$this->{$this->action}();
```

This works with methods and properties. `$objref->{ [expression] }` is the same as `$objref->hello` **if** the `[expression]` evaluates to `hello`.

Comment: Rereading his question and your response I understand what he was after. Good solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function.

Untested, but it may look something like this:

```
call_user_func($this->action);
```

Comment: call_user_func(array($this,$this->action)); surely

Comment: This could work too. If you want to call an instance method you have to supply an array with the object instance too (see [callbacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) for more on that). That would look like `call_user_func(array($this, $this->action));`